# Unsure where to apply KeyListener

Tags: java, javafx, keylistener

I'm new to JavaFX and I've done my fair share of research but I haven't found where exactly to add my listener to.

I've created a GridPane 10x10 with each slot of the grid being an ImageView holding an Image. These images represent my board elements such as walls, boxes, actor etc. When the user uses the arrow keys, the actor should move across the board (I've got plenty of control methods to ensure the move is valid).

My current code for the movement would be:

```
grid.setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent event) -> {
       if(event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.LEFT)){
           if (dc.afhandelingKeyEvents("Links")){
               grid.getChildren().remove(arrayViews[ventjeX][ventjeY]);
               ImageView imv = new ImageView();
               imv.setImage(mannetje);
               grid.add(imv, ventjeX -1, ventjeY);
           }
```

It'd be similar for right, top and bottom. Problem is, it's not doing anything.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a question ? We don't know either wjat's going wrong, since you're not telling us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.setOnKeyPressed()` on a node will trigger when this node is selected. What you really want is to capture any key press. You can do this by calling `.setOnKeyPressed()` on the `Scene` object.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was indeed doubting if it was correct!